# Report Viewer Group Number

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportviewer

How to get Group Number in Report Viewer, ex I'd to show report :

The data

```
Doc_no    Item
IV001     ABC
IV001     XYZ  
IV002     ABC
IV002     XYZ
```

The report I'd to produce

```
No Doc_no    Item
1  IV001     ABC
             XYZ  
2  IV002     ABC
             XYZ
```

I could create this number from a stored procedure first but if could I'd like to let RV do the numbering jobs.

This Group Number can easily produce in Crystal Report using Running Total, but in RV similar function like RunningValue does not have conditional sum, i tried using code combining Sum and  Previous(values)<>values but RV produce error if Prev function in aggre function.

Is there a build-in function or other ways to do this

TIA
Sen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible with your data.

I created a simple report based on your Dataset:

[image]

The expression for **No** is:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Doc_no.Value, CountDistinct, "DataSet1")
```

End result is as required:

[image]

I think the key to getting your `RunningValue` expression going is having the correct aggregate i.e. `CountDistinct`, and making sure it's running in the correct Scope, i.e. your Dataset (`DataSet1` in this example).

Comment: Thx Ian, works perfectly, I did search & search but no clue. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for the update, glad it helped! If an answer solves your issues, please consider setting it as accepted http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.